# Wifi on Lenovo P1 with Ubuntu 18.04 no longer works

Tags: networking, lenovo, iwlwifi

I followed a tutorial that recommended installing Ubuntu 16 LTS at first and then upgrading to 18.04 to deal with the long boot time problem due to random number generation. During installation, wireless worked fine. After upgrading to Ubuntu 18.04 at some point the wifi started giving errors, perhaps immediately, I'm not sure. The errors involved microcode errors. I did updates and those went away but the wireless still gives errors. Here is the [results](https://paste.ubuntu.com/p/Pdk7nS7rBh/) of running a wireless script of info.

Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try to install the HWE kernel which may include newer stable drivers for your hardware and reboot.

Open a terminal window, then run the following command.

```
sudo apt install --install-suggests linux-image-generic-hwe-18.04
```

Hit `ENTER` if asked about installing new packages, wait until the installation is done, then reboot.

```
sudo reboot
```

I hope it helps :)

Comment: This worked thanks, except just rebooting didn't work, i had to shutdown completely and then turn the machine on to get it to recognize the wireless for some reason.

Comment: Strange indeed. Nevertheless, I'm happy that it helped :)