# Wireless Adapter Vanished after Update in 19.10, Lenovo Xiaoxin 15

Tags: networking, drivers, wireless, lenovo, iwlwifi

After a recent update from ubuntu 19.10, I reboot my PC. After reboot, I discovered that there is no wifi-Adapter available. To install wifi Adapter manually I tried the command :

```
sudo lshw -C network
```

It produces the following output

```
    *-network                 
   description: Network controller
   product: Intel Corporation
   vendor: Intel Corporation
   physical id: 14.3
   bus info: pci@0000:00:14.3
   version: 00
   width: 64 bits
   clock: 33MHz
   capabilities: pm msi pciexpress msix bus_master cap_list
   configuration: driver=iwlwifi latency=0
   resources: irq:16 memory:a4318000-a431bfff


 *-network
   description: Ethernet interface
   physical id: 3
   bus info: usb@1:6
   logical name: enp0s20f0u6
   serial: de:ad:12:86:9b:1f
   capabilities: ethernet physical
   configuration: broadcast=yes driver=rndis_host driverversion=22-Aug-2005 firmware=RNDIS device ip=192.168.42.170 link=yes multicast=yes
```

To investigate detail about the wireless PCI I also tried the following

```
lspci -nnk | grep 0280 -A2
```

which shows,

```
00:14.3 Network controller [0280]: Intel Corporation Device [8086:02f0]
Subsystem: Intel Corporation Device [8086:0034]
Kernel driver in use: iwlwifi
```

I am in a fix what to do or how/which driver to install.

BTW, I cant not find the manufacturer of the wireless device.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I was able to restore my Wi-Fi by loading with previous kernel and removing the newest one.

[ThinkPad No Wi-Fi adapter found](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1211871/thinkpad-no-wi-fi-adapter-found)

Numbers can be different

Comment: It works !! thanks, but is this the problem is regarding the latest specific kernel version, Due to some bug or the problem is going to happen again on the future kernels that still remains unanswered.

Comment: I hope they will fix it in future, otherwise we will not be able to update =(